# How to insert multiply widgets in same page?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to insert this multiply times on a single page (HTML) I tried to copy and paste but it didn't work.

```html
<a 
    class="minerstat-widget" 
    title="BTC mining calculator" data-coin="BTC" 
    data-algo="SHA-256" 
    data-info="no" 
    data-style="light" 
    data-color="" 
    data-unit="TH" 
    data-hashrate="100" 
    data-width="300" 
    rel="nofollow" 
    href="https://minerstat.com/coin/BTC">Bitcoin mining calculator</a>
<script async src="https://api.minerstat.com/v2/widgets/coin.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Output:

[image: output]

Input:

[image: input]

Comment: copy and paste?

Comment: use a for loop with an append

Answer (score 0):

Run tag in the loop as per your required rows

```
<script async src="https://api.minerstat.com/v2/widgets/coin.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

<div id="bitcoin">
</div>

<script>
for(var i=1; i<=10; i++) {
        var newspan = document.createElement('span');
    newspan.innerHTML = '<a class="minerstat-widget" title="BTC mining calculator" data-coin="BTC" data-algo="SHA-256" data-info="no" data-style="light" data-color="" data-unit="TH" data-hashrate="100" data-width="300" rel="nofollow" href="https://minerstat.com/coin/BTC">Bitcoin mining calculator</a><br>';
        document.getElementById('bitcoin').appendChild(newspan);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply it did not work

Comment: No, I post picture see, please